# List search in pandas text column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with two columns: `date` and `text`. The `text` column contains unstructured information. I have a list of city names to search for in a `text` column.

I need to get two sets of data:

`list_city = [New York, Los Angeles, Chicago]`

1. When all records from the list with a text message match with the dataframe lines

Sample example:

```
df_1
data         text
06-02-2022   New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix
05-02-2022   New York, Houston, Phoenix
04-02-2022   San Antonio, San Diego, Jacksonville
```

Need result `df_1_res`:

```
df_1_res
data         text
06-02-2022   New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix
```

I tried this design, it works, but it doesn't look very nice:

```
df_1_res= df_1.loc[df_1["text"].str.contains(list_city[0]) & df_1["text"].str.contains(list_city[1]) & df_1["text"].str.contains(list_city[2])]
```

2. When at least one value from the list matches the text in the dataframe lines

Sample example:

```
df_2
data         text
06-02-2022   New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix
05-02-2022   New York, Houston, Phoenix
04-02-2022   San Antonio, San Diego, Jacksonville
```

Need result `df_2_res`:

```
df_2_res
data         text
06-02-2022   New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix
05-02-2022   New York, Houston, Phoenix
```

I tried this design, it works, but it doesn't look very nice:

```
df_2_res= df_2.loc[df_1["text"].str.contains(list_city[0]) | df_2["text"].str.contains(list_city[1]) | df_2["text"].str.contains(list_city[2])]
```

How can it be improved? Since it is planned to change the number of cities in the filtering list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one way to do it

For case # 1 : AND Condition

```
# use re.IGNORECASE to make findall case insensitive

import re
(df_1.loc[df_1['text'].str
        .findall(r'|'.join(list_city),  re.IGNORECASE)
        .apply(lambda x: len(x)).eq(len(list_city))])
```

```
data    text
0   06-02-2022  New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix
```

CASE #2 : OR Condition

```
#create an OR condition using join
# filter using loc

df_2.loc[df_1['text'].str.contains(r'|'.join(list_city))]
```

```
    data        text
0   06-02-2022  New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix
1   05-02-2022  New York, Houston, Phoenix
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `isin() function`
[image: check out how to use isin function]

Output:

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [`pandas.Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas.Series.str.count)

```
list_city = ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago']
print('\nfirst task - ALL')
df1 = df[df['text'].str.count(r'|'.join(list_city)).eq(len(list_city))]
print(df1)

print('\nsecond task - ANY')
df1 = df[df['text'].str.count(r'|'.join(list_city)).gt(0)]
print(df1)
```

```
first task - ALL
         data                                     text
0  06-02-2022  New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix

second task - ANY
         data                                     text
0  06-02-2022  New York, Los Angeles, Chicago, Phoenix
1  05-02-2022               New York, Houston, Phoenix
```